# In which case it is used more processing?

Tags: process

If have this situation:

```
int baseValue = (3 * value) / 100
```

and use this value in various cases.

```
int width = baseValue;
int height = baseValue;
int length = baseValue;
```

Exist something of difference, of do this more of one time?
(This is not case, only ask by question of doubt)

ex:

```
int width = (3 * value) / 100;
int height = (3 * value) / 100;
int length = (3 * value) / 100;
```

in all cases the result be the same

Would use more processing in this case?

Thanks...

Comment: `Exist something of difference, of do this more of one time? (This is not case, only ask by question of doubt)` this is complete word salad

Comment: I think i understand...  there might be a nano second difference using the direct assignment over the calc but this is essentially irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and sorry for my english....I did the tests, and "save" the value in a variable fared more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allocating a variable takes less processing than calculating the same again I think, might help you to try to understand how this on byte level works.
But why do you ask such a question? If you're interested in the answer just make a test program and log the times.